# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType' python3

Tags: python

I am a beginner Python programmer and I've been trying to solidify what I've learned by making little games. This is a first "bigger" game I've worked on. The main question is, when I use the spit option for attack I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home//Desktop/save_princess_peach.py", line 49, in <module>
    taking_damage(attack_dmg)
  File "/home//Desktop/save_princess_peach.py", line 42, in taking_damage
    bowser['HP'] = bowser['HP'] - damage
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

What have I done wrong. By the way, if you guys don't mind giving me tips about my code, and where I could improve it. Thanks!

```
import random

bowser = {'HP': 0, 'attack': 10}
checktoc = True
print("Oh no! Bowser has captured Princess Peach again! Mario got dementia and needs your help! Choose the difficulty on your journey to help Mario\n\n")
diff = input("Choose difficulty: \n e - easy | m - medium | h - hard\n")

if diff == 'e':
    bowser['HP'] = 50
elif diff == 'm':
    bowser['HP'] = 75
elif diff == 'h':
    bowser['HP'] = 100
else:
    checktoc = False
    print("Wrong input!")

attacks = {'k': 10, 'p': 5, 's': 1}
player = {'HP': 100}

def attack_phase(att):
    if att == 'k':
        n = random.randint(1,5)
        if n == 5:
            print("Critical attack!")
            return attacks['k'] * 1.5
        else:
            return attacks['k']
    elif att == 'p':
        n = random.randint(1,3)
        if n == 3:
            print("Critical attack!")
            return attacks['p'] * 2
        else:
            return attacks['p']
    elif att == 's':
        bowser['attack'] -= 1

def taking_damage(damage):
    player['HP'] = player['HP'] - bowser['attack']
    print("New player HP: " + str(player['HP']))
    bowser['HP'] = bowser['HP'] - damage
    print("On the other hand, Bowser has: " + str(bowser['HP']) + "\n")
if checktoc == True:        
    print("Choose your attack!\n")
    while bowser['HP'] != 0:
        attack = input("k - kick | p - punch | s - spit: ")
        attack_dmg = attack_phase(attack)
        taking_damage(attack_dmg)
        if bowser['HP'] != 0:
            print("New round!\n")

    if bowser['HP'] == 0:
        print("You won! Princess Peach is saved\n Here's a cookie! O")
    elif player['HP'] == 0:
        print("Oh no! You lost!")
else:
    print("Dummy!")
```

Comment: In some cases, you don't return anything explicitely from `attack_phase`, so it returns `None`.

Comment: `damage` is `None` in `taking_damage`. You are passing a `None` value as argument to that function. Probably as a result of what is mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: What Thierry said. Hint: look at you 2nd elif in attack_phase.

Comment: As an aside, don’t have a function call itself to “go back to the top of the function” as in `taking_damage`, use a `while` loop. This is called recursion and has unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't returned the att=='s'. Please return the value as you did for 'k' and 'p' then your code will execute.

```py
elif att == 's':
    bowser['attack'] -= 1
    return bowser['attack']
```

Also check the condition if we not pass option 'k' 'p' or 's' program terminates, handle with some message.

Check the below code

```py
import random
bowser = {'HP': 0, 'attack': 10}
checktoc = True
print("Oh no! Bowser has captured Princess Peach again! Mario got dementia and needs your help! Choose the difficulty on your journey to help Mario\n\n")
diff = input("Choose difficulty: \n e - easy | m - medium | h - hard\n")

if diff == 'e':
    bowser['HP'] = 50
elif diff == 'm':
    bowser['HP'] = 75
elif diff == 'h':
    bowser['HP'] = 100
else:
    checktoc = False
    print("Wrong input!")

attacks = {'k': 10, 'p': 5, 's': 1}
player = {'HP': 100}

def attack_phase(att):
    if att == 'k':
        n = random.randint(1,5)
        if n == 5:
            print("Critical attack!")
            return attacks['k'] * 1.5
        else:
            return attacks['k']
    elif att == 'p':
        n = random.randint(1,3)
        if n == 3:
            print("Critical attack!")
            return attacks['p'] * 2
        else:
            return attacks['p']
    elif att == 's':
        bowser['attack'] -= 1
        return bowser['attack']

def taking_damage(damage):
    player['HP'] = player['HP'] - bowser['attack']
    print("New player HP: " + str(player['HP']))
    bowser['HP'] = bowser['HP'] - damage
    print("On the other hand, Bowser has: " + str(bowser['HP']) + "\n")
if checktoc == True:        
    print("Choose your attack!\n")
    while bowser['HP'] != 0:
        attack = input("k - kick | p - punch | s - spit: ")
        if attack != '':
            pass
        else:
            print('Wrong Input')
            exit(1)
        attack_dmg = attack_phase(attack)
        taking_damage(attack_dmg)
        if bowser['HP'] != 0:
            print("New round!\n")

    if bowser['HP'] == 0:
        print("You won! Princess Peach is saved\n Here's a cookie! O")
    elif player['HP'] == 0:
        print("Oh no! You lost!")
else:
    print("Dummy!")
```